# Could not get a expected Response through a POST request

Tags: post, postman, payment-gateway

I am working this API https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference-0#operation/createCi.

I faced an issue, when creating card-identifier. I could not get an expected response.
The test API is https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/card-identifiers

To create a Card Identifier, We need a merchantKey to use as a bearerToken and request body is

`{ "cardholderName": "Spongebob Squarepants", "cardNumber": "4929000000006", "expiryDate": "0223", "securityCode": "123" }`

To create merchantKey use this https://reqbin.com/pzag38mw

To create Card Identifieruse this https://reqbin.com/zkhuuecs

And I added My postamn request here.

My postman http request for create Card Identifier.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/card-identifiers' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer E0780245-2701-4748-924A-A1D5A904EB62' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: AWSALB=o44OLd5fFLrFUD4meQBU0sxMs64iiql4YlDlppQILCFio+6pOo16e+tLu7SaI+F8sDS8CgSrRTwOcMo//ODTGcJGgNSTHPHxrP5hs87mkM1I1Xos3F0hDEoTD4dV; AWSALBCORS=o44OLd5fFLrFUD4meQBU0sxMs64iiql4YlDlppQILCFio+6pOo16e+tLu7SaI+F8sDS8CgSrRTwOcMo//ODTGcJGgNSTHPHxrP5hs87mkM1I1Xos3F0hDEoTD4dV' \
--data-raw '{
  "cardholderName": "Spongebob Squarepants",
  "cardNumber": "4929000000006",
  "expiryDate": "0223",
  "securityCode": "123"

}'
```

I got this Response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "description": "Missing mandatory field",
            "property": "cardDetails.cardNumber",
            "clientMessage": "The card number is required",
            "code": 1003
        },
        {
            "description": "Missing mandatory field",
            "property": "cardDetails.cardholderName",
            "clientMessage": "The cardholder name is required",
            "code": 1003
        },
        {
            "description": "Contains invalid value",
            "property": "cardDetails.expiryDate",
            "clientMessage": "The expiry date is invalid",
            "code": 1009
        },
        {
            "description": "Missing mandatory field",
            "property": "cardDetails.expiryDate",
            "clientMessage": "The expiry date is required",
            "code": 1003
        }
    ]
}
```

But The response sholud be somthing like this:

```
{
"cardIdentifier": "C6F92981-8C2D-457A-AA1E-16EBCD6D3AC6",
"expiry": "2015-08-11T10:45:16.285Z",
"cardType": "Visa"
}
```

What is the mistake I did when I sent a post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the method of posting you are using in postman. If you are unsure edit to add a screenshot. Check if you have selected:
[image]

As if you use another method it may not read it

So once you have set that instead of sending you data as:

```
{
  "cardholderName": "Spongebob Squarepants",
  "cardNumber": "4929000000006",
  "expiryDate": "0223",
  "securityCode": "123"
}
```

You should send it as:

```
{ "cardDetails":
{
    "cardholderName": "Spongebob Squarepants",
    "cardNumber": "4929000000006",
    "expiryDate": "0223",
    "securityCode": "123"
}
}
```

This is because it is asking the data from under cardDetails
Please tick this if it fixed your problem so I know

Comment: I did as you said. ` https://reqbin.com/zkhuuecs this is online API request checker. Please read the question.

Comment: @hanushic my bad i will look into it more

Comment: @hanushic i found the problem